# Which tab is selected, onTabSelected Android

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

hi im making simple android app with actionbar with tabs. i go a question, how to check in the function onTabSelected() which tab is seleced ? i did something like that but it doesnt work:

```
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if(tab.getText().equals(R.string.title_section_video))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerListViewActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }       
  }
```

and one more question, i was reading some examples and everywhere ppl are using fragments instead of activity, i sounds really good for me to change only a part of my screen, i want to keep my action bar still and only the part below tabs need to change, how i can do this using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the String returned from getText() against the Integer R.string....

Try this:

```
if(tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.title_section_video)))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerListViewActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

getString() returns the String you specified in the strings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

```
(1st tab is 0 ,2nd tab is 1 so on...)   int i = tab.getPosition();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```